# ctags doesn't use my custom .ctags on Mac OS

Tags: ctags

I'm trying to use exuberant ctags on Mac OS. I've already installed exuberant ctags with `homebrew`. Here is my version :

```
$ ctags --version
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
```

It seems that my custom `$HOME/.ctags` is not taken into account.

Here is my config :

```
$ cat ~/.ctags
--verbose=no
--recurse=yes
--tag-relative=yes
--langdef=scala
--langmap=scala:.scala
--regex-scala=/^\s*class\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\1/c,classes/
…
```

When I launch `ctags -R`, no tags are generated for `.scala` files.

When I test with `--options`

```
$ctags -R --options=/Users/yamo/.ctags
ctags: cannot open option file "/Users/yamo/.ctags" : No such file or directory

$ll ~/.ctags
lrwxr-xr-x  1 yamo  staff  36 Apr 13 21:29 /Users/yamo/.ctags@ -> /Users/yamo/Projects/dotfiles/.ctags
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that ctags doesn't like the symlink for some reason? Can it find the file if you give it the path to the original?

Answer (score 3):

The issue was due to BSD Regex.

I've just solved it by editing `~/.ctags` in Vim `:%s/\\s/[ \\t]/g`

Comment: Keyword: whitespace.  `\s` does not match whitespace on Mac OS X with (exuberant) ctags installed via homebrew.  For portability, use `[ \t]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should place your config files under `~/.ctags.d/` folder, according to the docs.
I got the same issue and doing that works for me:

```
   $HOME/.ctags.d/*.ctags

   $HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH/ctags.d/*.ctags (on MSWindows only)

   .ctags.d/*.ctags

   ctags.d/*.ctags
      If any of these configuration files exist, each will be expected to contain a set of default options which are read in the order listed when ctags starts, but before the CTAGS
      environment variable is read or any command line options are read. This makes it possible to set up personal or project-level defaults. It is possible to compile ctags to read
      an  additional  configuration  file  before  any  of those shown above, which will be indicated if the output produced by the --version option lists the "custom-conf" feature.
      Options appearing in the CTAGS environment variable or on the command line will override options specified in these files. Only options will be read  from  these  files.  Note
      that  the  option files are read in line-oriented mode in which spaces are significant (since shell quoting is not possible) but spaces at the beginning of a line are ignored.
      Each line of the file is read as one command line parameter (as if it were quoted with single quotes).  Therefore, use new lines to indicate separate  command-line  arguments.
      A line starting with '#' is treated as a comment.

      *.ctags files in a directory are loaded in alphabetical order.

   tags   The default tag file created by ctags.

   TAGS   The default tag file created by etags.
```